# Androidx Robolectric configuration

Tags: kotlin, robolectric

I'm trying to use Robolectric in my project but I have hit a snag and don't know how to resolve it. I think its a configuration issue since I am unable to get even the most basic tests to run.

Here are my dependencies;

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation ('org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1') {
    exclude group: "org.apache.maven"
}
```

If I don't include the exclude group directive I get a bunch of library conflicts.

Here is my first test;

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class RoboTest {

    @Test
    fun test() {
        Thread.sleep(9000)
    }
}
```

When I try to run it i get the following stacktrace;

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.robolectric.util.inject.-$$Lambda$Injector$ZRemX9RoMk8gdKE-8yBtX0b79nc
at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.getProvider(Injector.java:310)
at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.getInstanceInternal(Injector.java:213)
at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.getInstance(Injector.java:197)
at org.robolectric.util.inject.Injector.getInstance(Injector.java:191)
at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.<init>(SandboxTestRunner.java:73)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.<init>(RobolectricTestRunner.java:101)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.<init>(RobolectricTestRunner.java:96)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.junit4.AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidAnnotatedBuilder.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.AndroidRunnerBuilder.runnerForClass(AndroidRunnerBuilder.java:153)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.doCreateRunner(TestLoader.java:73)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestLoader.getRunnersFor(TestLoader.java:104)
at androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.build(TestRequestBuilder.java:793)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.buildRequest(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:547)
at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:390)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)
```

I've tried googling it but I don't think i've been able to find the same case I've been running into, I have also tried Invalidating cache/restarting which hasn't done anything.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I moved the file to `/test` (unit test) from `/androidtest` and updated the dependencies accordingly;

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android'
/*androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'*/
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation ('org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3.1')
```

The solution was alluded to in the [docs](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/).

Oh boy, do I have egg on my face.